# df.groupby('month_year').sum()['sales'] produce error

Tags: pandas

Newbie in Python.

I have dataframe with structure like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjof2.png)

When I'm using this command -> **df_trend = df.groupby('month_year').sum()['sales']**
throw me an error saying "TypeError: datetime64 type does not support sum operations"

Why ? Ain't the group by based on 'month_year' ? and how to resolve this ?
Thanks

tried to dropna() as I thought there are some NaN.

Comment: Use `df_trend = df.groupby('month_year')['sales'].sum()`